# PHP how to validate number with punctuation

Tags: php, preg-match

I want to validate a phone number input. The phone numbers should be mix of numeric number and some of the punctuation, like -,+ ,( and ).

The input don't have specific format, it can be

- 014-455464564
- +6054-4554
- (+60)-4554

How can I do that in  preg_match?

Comment: I guess it's not a duplicate, but here's an entry that may help you, http://stackoverflow.com/q/123559/527096

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this one works based on your examples.

```
$pattern = '/^[0-9_\-\+\(\)\ ]+$/';

    $val = '014-455464564';
    if (preg_match($pattern, $val))
        echo $val.' TRUE<br />';
    else
        echo $val.' FALSE<br />';

    $val = '+6054-4554';
    if (preg_match($pattern, $val))
        echo $val.' TRUE<br />';
    else
        echo $val.' FALSE<br />';

    $val = '(+60)-4554';
    if (preg_match($pattern, $val))
        echo $val.' TRUE<br />';
    else
        echo $val.' FALSE<br />';

    $val = '(+60)-4554-sss';
    if (preg_match($pattern, $val))
        echo $val.' TRUE<br />';
    else
        echo $val.' FALSE<br />';

    $val = '(+60)-4 554';
    if (preg_match($pattern, $val))
        echo $val.' TRUE<br />';
    else
        echo $val.' FALSE<br />';
```

Also you may want to check http://regexlib.com